# VBA: Error handling on close file

Tags: ms-access, vb6, vba

I have a VBA code that creates a file and need to have an error handling routine in case something happens in which the file closes (If it is actually open at all).

If the file is open and crashes before it gets to  *Close #F*, or even before it is actually created.

```
Sub test1()
On Error GoTo Err

    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim F As Integer

    F = FreeFile

    Open "C:\MYFILE.TXT" For Output As #F

    ' My code that does lots of stuff...

    If Not rs Is Nothing Then rs.Close
    Close #F

Exit_Sub:
    Set rs = Nothing
    Exit Sub
Err:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_Sub 

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this part

```
Exit_Sub:
    Set rs = Nothing
    Exit Sub
```

to

```
Exit_Sub:
    On Error Resume Next
    Close #F
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set rs = Nothing
    Exit Sub
```

And remove the `Close #F` from where it was earlier...